# when arrays are implicitlly converted to pointers in c

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have often heared that arrays are implicitly converted to pointers but 
how and when it is needed . Do strings also implicitally converted to pointers?
A more common word i heared is array is decade into pointer so when and how it happens plzz show
programming example.

Comment: Strings in C are merely arrays of chars, so yes, they implicitly convert to pointers just like any other array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its true that *array expressions* in C are generally *converted to* pointer expressions, and can be observed as such...  For example, given this simple demo code:

```
#include <ansi_c.h>
int main(void)
{
    int a[20]={2,3,5,8,6,4,3,2,1,7,8,9,0,4,6,7,8,9,0,2};
    char s[3][10] = {"one","two","three"};
    char *pS;

    pS = calloc (20, sizeof(char));//char array of 20 bytes, (string)

    strcpy(pS, "this is a string");

    printf("a[1] = %d\n", a[1]);
    printf("a (pointer) = %p\n\n", a);
    printf("s[0] = %s\ns[1] = %s\ns[2] = %s\n", s[0], s[1], s[2]);
    printf("s (pointer) = %p\n\n", s);
    printf("pS = %s\npS (pointer) = %p\n", pS, pS);

    free(pS);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Yields this output showing pointer (address of)  to first element of array a:
[image]

Comment: Arrays *are not* pointers; array *expressions* are converted to pointer expressoins under most circumstances.

Comment: @JohnBode - thank you.  Fixed the first sentence.  And +1 for the reference in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

From the [horse's mouth](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> **6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators**
> ...
> 3 Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the
> unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has
> type ‘‘array of *type*’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to *type*’’ that points
> to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object has
> register storage class, the behavior is undeﬁned.

Given the following code:

```
char foo[]="This is a test";

printf( "Contents of foo = \"%s\"\n", foo );      // prints "This is a test"
printf( "Value of foo = %p\n", (void *) foo );    // prints address of first element
printf( "Value of &foo = %p\n", (void *) &foo );  // prints address of array
printf( "Size of foo = %zu\n", sizeof foo );      // prints number of bytes used
                                                  //   by foo
```

The type of the *expression* `foo` is "15-element array of `char`".  In the first two `printf` calls, the expression `foo` is not the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, so it is converted to an expression of type "pointer to `char`" and its value is the address of the first element in the array; this pointer value is what gets passed to `printf`.

In the third `printf` call, the expression `foo` is the operand of the unary `&` operator, so the conversion rule doesn't apply; the type of the expression `&foo` is "pointer to *15-element array of* `char`".  The last two lines will print the same value (the address of the array is the same as the address of the first element of the array), but the types are different.

In the last `printf` call, the expression `foo` is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, so the conversion rule doesn't apply; the result of the expression `sizeof foo` is the total number of bytes allocated to the array (15).

Note that the *object* designated by `foo` is an array, not a pointer; no storage is set aside for a pointer object apart from the array elements themselves.

Comment: But second printf yields the string itself not address

Comment: @user3287033: Not with the `%p` conversion specifier, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

when it is needed?
Often. It's convenient. For example `strlen(s)` looks less ugly than `strlen(&s[0])`, first is the implicit conversion, and both are equal

Do strings also implicitally converted to pointers?
yes.

Working with arrays and pointers is almost the same. there are differences:

- array variable can't be l-value
- `sizeof(array)` differs from `sizeof(pointer)`

function arguments, even when declared as arrays, are really just pointers. they can be l-value and sizeof() on them returns size of pointer